# is there something wrong with this php code?

Tags: php, database

is this piece of code correct syntax wise ?

I need to update some fields in a certain row in my database which i can access using email ... so is this right ?

```
public function storeData($emaill, $servicee, $ratee, $rated_clientss) {
    $email = "samy@gmail.com";
    $service = "lksdjfsdkljf";
    $rate = "good";
    $rated_clients = "20";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare ( "UPDATE users SET service='$service' and SET rate='$rate' and SET rated_clients='$rated_clients' WHERE email='$email'" );
    var_dump($stmt->execute ());

    if ($stmt->execute ()) {
        $data = $stmt->get_result ()->fetch_assoc ();
        $stmt->close ();
        return $data;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: "is this piece of code correct syntax wise?" You can easily test that yourself by simply executing it. Any syntax error will immediately show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepared statments to not directly accept user input, instead, you need to pass them as a placeholder: `?`, and then use `bind_param()` to fill in the type and the variable.

Observe:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare ( "UPDATE users SET service=? and SET rate=? and SET rated_clients=? WHERE email=?" );
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $service, $rate, $rated_clients, $email);
```

Now you can correctly `->execute` the `$stmt`.